# Why does Parallel Python work the way it does?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parallel-python

In Parallel Python, why is it necessary to wrap any modules the function passed will need along with variables and namespaces in that job submission call - how necessary is it to preserve module level "global" variables? (if that's all that's going on)

submit function:

```
submit(self, func, args=(), depfuncs=(), modules=(), callback=None, callbackargs=(),group='default', globals=None)
    Submits function to the execution queue

    func - function to be executed
    args - tuple with arguments of the 'func'
    depfuncs - tuple with functions which might be called from 'func'
    modules - tuple with module names to import
    callback - callback function which will be called with argument 
        list equal to callbackargs+(result,) 
        as soon as calculation is done
    callbackargs - additional arguments for callback function
    group - job group, is used when wait(group) is called to wait for
    jobs in a given group to finish
    globals - dictionary from which all modules, functions and classes
    will be imported, for instance: globals=globals()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `pp` works the way it does, is that it makes a fresh instance of the Python interpreter for every worker, which is completely independent from anything that has run before or since. This ensures that there are no unintended side-effects, such as `__future__` imports being active in the worker process. The problem with this is that it makes things way more complicated to get right, and in my experience with `pp`, not particularly robust. `pp` *does* try to make things a bit easier for the user, but seems to introduce more problems than it solves in its efforts to do that.

If I were to write code that was designed for use on a cluster from the start, I would probably end up using `pp`, but I've found that adapting existing code to work with `pp` is a nightmare.